# The entity's form doesn't get updated

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have a HTML file, which I've uploaded as a web resource and linked to via an activity's form designer in an IFRAME. So far, so good.

Then, when I edited the source file locally and uploaded it (browse-save-publish, of course), I got no difference in the appearance on the screen. Here's the weird part. When I open the uploaded file in the editor, I can see the changes to my source code. On the RTF tab I can also see the change in colors of the background.

However, reloading the "create new"-form doesn't bring those changes to the client! I've tried restarting the window, restarting IE, clearing the cache. Nothing helps.

When I entered the very same page from a different client, I got to see the updated version. But after that, the subsequent changes are not updated either. It's like if IE thinks "oh, matey, ya wanna cache that for life, I see". Well, I don't. I'd like to see my edition in action pretty much directly and without creating a new account with a new client. :)

After a while, the update seems to go through and I get to see a new version but not in all browsers.

What is causing it?! How do I kill it?

(Win8/IE10/CRM11OL)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen CRM do some weird IIS Caching.  I'd assume this is a server side issue, but your using crm online, they won't let you run an IIS reset now will they?  :) Have you tried running it on a new client in private browsing mode, deploying your change, and opening a new private browser to test if it is a client caching issue or a server caching issue?

Comment: CRM11OL = CRM 2011 on-line. I think MS would object if I want to reset their cloud service. :)    Sorry - I should've been more clear on that. However, it still is weird and I'm guessing that it's some kind of relay.issue because when I got back after lunch, everything was up to speed. Weird indeed...